# Remove Layer with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Is it possible to remove a specific layer in a pdf file with ghostscript ? (with linux command line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `gs` command here](https://superuser.com/a/1120422/261550) to figure out where the OCRed text is and, as [@LarsKotthof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102702/remove-layer-with-ghostscript#comment11434877_9102855) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102702/remove-layer-with-ghostscript#comment11434877_9102855), use [PDFCrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) to remove the margins that contain text.

Answer (score -1):

No. As far as I know, none of the Linux commandline tools to handle PDF files can do that.

Comment: thks, ...
then, is it possible to remove spot color in the pdf (used for offset printing) ?

Comment: You could try using [PDFCrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) to remove the margins that contain these. It has an option to specify a margin beyond what it detects as white space.

Comment: Does Somenone have info about how to use  the Layer data extraction utilities of Illustrator files : pdf_cslayer.ps ??

Comment: I don't have a file to try but "gswin32..... pdf_cslayer.ps <input.pdf> should do it.

Comment: That's a very broad statement and it also isn't true. There are definitely Linux command-line tools that can do this.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche As I've said -- as far as I know. If you know how to do it, please post as an answer, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: The question of the OP concerns GhostScript specifically - I'm far from an expert on that, though the answer of KenS seems to indicate it's possible there too. I do know about the commercial solution of callas software (as I'm involved with it) which can definitely work with layers (OCGs) and is available on Linux using command-line.